# MOC3041 TRIAC Dimming Circuit

Tags: power-electronics, solid-state-relay, triac

Details: I try to build the single TRIAC circuit for ON/OFF, Dimmer(600W AC Light), and AC fan Speed Control. I trying this the first time.
Problem: I using MOC3041 to control the TRIAC ON/OFF it seems to work fine but while I Tried Dimming I found using MOC3041 cant able dim the lamp due to Zero crossing in the MOC3041. Now I try to change MOC3041 to MOC3052, Please clarify to me what are the things I need to take care of before proceeding.
What will happen to my switching if I change MOC3041 to MOC3052?
Note: snubber Circuit value - Rs-50E/1W, Cs-0.01uF/400V[image: []
Thank You.

Comment: What's your plan to create the fire signal (from uC)? Do you detect the zero-cross somehow before firing the Opto? If you detect the zero-cross and the firing signal is synced and phase-shifted, you are on the right track. Just notice that for tungsten light, the dimmer will work ok; but, for motor, there will be some problems; like, it won't work linear and near the full power, the Triac won't turn-off because of inductive load.

Comment: While I try to Dim the tungsten light with reference to Externally added zero-cross detection the lamp got flickering. I can`t able to dim the lamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This is the main difference  :

[image]

At the desired phase angle (zero cross + delay)  you turn the triac ON. at the next zero cross you turn the triac OFF.

Comment: Hai Mr.Marko Buršič Reading some detail in the forum I understand changing MOC3052
will help with dimming and speed control. But I need to know what about switching ON/OFF the same load.

Comment: @Karthick You should keep the opto ON/OFF all the time. Your triac is quite big, so don't expect to work perfectly with light load due to higher holding current.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mr.Marko Buršič